# Laravel cache DatabaseStore clean up

Tags: caching, store, scheduler, laravel-5.6

I use cache DatabaseStore for managing mutex files with Laravel scheduler.

I modified app/Console/Kernel.php a bit to make this work.

```
protected function defineConsoleSchedule()
{
    $this->app->bind(SchedulingMutex::class, function() {
        $container = Container::getInstance();
        $mutex = $container->make(CacheSchedulingMutex::class);
        return $mutex->useStore('database');
    });

    parent::defineConsoleSchedule();
}
```

I need it to be able to run scheduler on multiple servers, but it requires to have a shared storage. Since I have different Redis instances for all servers I decided to use database cache storage which is provided out of the box. 
All works fine, but the db table named **cache**, where all  things are stored does not get cleaned up even after cache expired.

Here is some tuples from the table:

```
key                                         value  expiration
laravelframework/schedule-015655105069...   b:1;   1539126032
laravelframework/schedule-015655105069...   b:1;   1539126654
```

So the first one, has expiration 1539126032 (2018-10-09 23:00:32), current time is 2018-10-10 08:09:45. I expect it to be cleaned up.

The question is - should I implement something to maintain this table or Laravel should handle it? What I'm doing wrong if it's Laravel's duty?

Comment: Expiration gets only checked at request time. If a key is never requested, it will remain there 'forever' (might be forced out during 'out of memory' conditions). Sadly it doesn't seem like DatabaseStore uses Redis native EXPIRE. You can check this in the implementation: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Cache/DatabaseStore.php#L94

Comment: Maybe RedisStore is more appropriate, it can put with seconds timeout: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Cache/RedisStore.php#L90